# Paifang inscription on a gate at the Yellow Crane Tower (Characters identified: 江山入画)

Tags: character-identification

I am having a hard time trying to identify a character inscribed on this gate at the Yellow Crane Tower.

[image]

I think I have been able to identify the other three characters (入山江). 
So the character I'd like to have identified is the character to the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be 江山入画. If you search for Yellow Crane and 江山入画, you will find a bunch of results confirming, for example [this one](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/2638628).

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that in ancient Chinese, words are read from right to left. Like here, "江山入画", not "画入山江". You can find examples in many places in China.